# How to properly use 'exist' function in mongodb like in sql?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

I'm using **Node.js + mongodb**. I have few documents in my collection and i want to know does my collection have any document matched my condition. Of course i can simply use
`myModel.find({ myField: someValue })` and check is anything comes or not. But i want to use solution like sql provides `exists` keyword? Help me, please

Edit: my bad. I forget to tell that "performance first".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB's `$exists` actually doesn't help you very much to find out if a certain document exists in your collection. It is used for example to give you all documents that have a specific field set.

MongoDB has no native support for an sql like exists. What you can use, however, is `myModel.findOne({ myField: someValue })` and then check if it is null.

To enhance performance you can tell MongoDB to only load the object id via projection, like this:

```
myModel.findOne({ myField: someValue }, {_id: 1})
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an exist mechanism in mongodb, I'll demonstrate a sample below.

For example below, I'm looking for records that have tomato.consensus fields and that it's empty, so I can delete them or avoid them. In case I was looking for "tomato.consensus": Dublin, I'd change Null to Dublin, to match that.

I hope this is helpful, if not fire away any questions

```
tomato
----consensus

db.movieDetails.updateMany({$and: [
        {"tomato.consensus": {$exists: true} },
        {"tomato.consensus": null} ] },
]})
```